# Color change during Super-Resolution

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, resolution, convolution

I am working on a CNN that does Super-Resolution. The training goes well, there is no overfitting but when I try the trained network on a low-res image, the output image has changed its color :

---

**The input image**

[image: The original image]

**The output image**

[image: The output image]

---

Even with a longer training, the result stay the same. Has someone ever faced a similar problem ?

My first idea was to change the output activation function to something that goes from 0 to 1 (sigmoid) instead of a ReLu but there is no improvement.

Here is my network implemented in Keras :

```
input_img = Input(shape=(None,None,3))

c1 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(input_img)
a1 = Activation('relu')(c1)

c2 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(a1)
a2 = Activation('relu')(c2)
b2 = BatchNormalization()(a2)

c3 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(b2)
a3 = Activation('relu')(c3)
b3 = BatchNormalization()(a3)

c4 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(b3)
a4 = Activation('relu')(c4)
b4 = BatchNormalization()(a4)

c5 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(b4)
a5 = Activation('relu')(c5)
b5 = BatchNormalization()(a5)

d1 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(b5)
a6 = Activation('relu')(d1)
b6 = BatchNormalization()(a6)

m1 = add([a4, b6])
a7 = Activation('relu')(m1)

d2 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(a7)
a8 = Activation('relu')(d2)
b8 = BatchNormalization()(a8)

d3 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(b8)
a9 = Activation('relu')(d3)
b9 = BatchNormalization()(a9)

m2 = add([a2, b9])
a10 = Activation('relu')(m2)

d4 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(a10)
a11 = Activation('relu')(d4)
b10 = BatchNormalization()(a11)

d5 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (3, 3))(b10)
a12 = Activation('relu')(d5)
b11 = BatchNormalization()(a12)

m3 = add([input_img, b11])
a13 = Activation('relu')(m3)

out = Convolution2D(3, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same') (a13)

model = Model(input_img, out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the goal is here? What exactly are you optimizing for?

Comment: This network takes an upsampled low res image as an input and bring a high res out. It has been trained with pairs of low res/high res images but when I try to do it with my test set, the results have faced a color change

Comment: Just looking at the example pictures, it seems the RGB range is being skewed, moving greens into yellows (meaning the green dimension has a higher value than expected). This may be an artefact of this particular image - is there a similar skew on images containing different colours? Have you tried using a different loss - https://keras.io/losses/?

Comment: Yes some other images don't have their color changed like this one. I'll probably try with MSE instead and see what happens

Comment: Was training data diverse enough, maybe the training data doesn't have a lot of green patches. Also try clipping the output in appropriate range (0 to 1 or 0 to 255).

Answer (score 0):

In most of the papers people first convert the image into YCrCb format, and process only the Y-channel (which contains all the relevant image details) with the CNN. The reconstructed Y-channel is then joined with the Cr and Cb channels which are upsampled using traditional bicubic interpolation (or the interpolation of your choice) and the image is then converted to RGB. Try this, it might work better.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem so just check if your pixels lie between 0 to 1 for the training dataset,
 for loss function it should be 0 to 255

Answer (score 0):

You can add a component to your loss function to ensure that the colors match the original. Add a loss component that downsamples the super-resolution image to that of the input, then use L1 or L2 loss to penalize for differences between input and output colors.

The key difference between this loss component and the one you're already using is that the existing loss compares output to ground truth, whereas this would compare output to input.